# Quickly retrieving svn directory trees

Tags: python, svn

I am working on a repository management system for my university that will provide a gui for modifying permissions to individual folders in a subversion repository, and make it easy for professors to add directories for students and TA's, with the appropriate permissions. In order to make this work, I need to be able to retrieve the directory structure of an existing svn repository, and present it on the web. I have looked at several methods, and was wondering if anyone had other ideas, or suggestions. Some things I have looked at:

Every hour, run a script that runs 'svn ls -R --xml'  on all of the repositories and populates a mysql database
Positive:

- Fast page loads afterwards
- Doesn't take a lot of disk space
- Easy to manage permission, i.e. the website doesn't need to touch svn directly at all

Negative:

- Really slow on some of our more complicated repositories
- No 'live' updates
- Has to run whether there are changes or not

On page load, run 'svn ls -R --xml' and retrieve only the directory I need to render the current page
Positive:

- updates live
- no cron job to tie up the server

Negative:

- website is slow as molasses
- webserver uses a lot more resources

Directly read svn database
Positive:

- Fast page loads
- live updates

Negative:

- Difficult?

I am very curious what alternatives there are that I have not seen or thought of, because I feel like any of these would be quite awful and inelegant in one way or another. Also I don't want to reinvent the wheel if it can be avoided.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can run code on the SVN server, try

```
svnlook tree /path/to/repo
```

This is very quick, because it reads the repository from disk directly :) See [the documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnlook) for more usage details.

Answer (score 1):

First, what is this for? Is this for source code? Is this some sort of Content Management System? Is this for storing and retrieving documents? You didn't say. What you want to use it for depends heavily on what type of tools you need.

If this is merely for sharing resources between professors, students, TAs, and departments, take a look at Dropbox.  It's simple and effective. This lets the professor decide who they want to share what with and leave you out of the picture.

Assuming this is for source control, there are several GUI server management systems that start out as free:

- [VisualSVNServer](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/)
- [UberSVN](http://www.wandisco.com/ubersvn)

This means nothing to write, no scripts, no MySql tables. It's already done for you. That's always the nicest solution.

However, **if** this is for source control, I'm going to recommend that you look at Git rather than Subversion because this is one of those times when a Distributed Version Control System like Git works better than a Centralized Version Control System like Subversion.

The problem is one of access. You have dozens of professors, hundreds of students, and fistfuls of TAs all wanting access. Who is going to setup accounts for all those people. Every year 1/4 of the student population is going to leave and another 1/4 will come in. Of course, there are students coming and going all the time. Plus, there will be teams. Each will need access. That's an administration headache you don't want.

Git helps by spreading the pain downward. In your Git master repository, the only ones who have access (at least push access. Pull access could be wider spread) will be the professors. Period. No one else will be allowed to submit changes to that repository. You've gone from giving permission to 500+ people to a mere dozen. And, these dozen usually stick around, so maintenance is minimal.

What about the students? That's up to the professors. The professors can make their Git repositories available to the students, and the students can push changes to the professor's repository. From there, the professor can push those changes to the master.

So first, you have to decide exactly what you want not in the terms of tools or how you think things will work, but actually what you want:

- Is it version control?
- Is it document repository?
- Is it a Wiki?
- Is it a Content Management System?
- Is it a way to share important documents between various groups?

Then, once you have that, it's easier to pick the tools. If you really want a University wide version control system, Git may fit your needs better since you don't want centralized access control, but to spread that responsibility downward.

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to a database solution.
The problem with a repository is simultaneous access. Using the database that stores the updates the repository gives you a reliable source of information to retrieve its layout.

I have done a fair amount of research for an internship and using a database is almost always the fastest way in which you can read the repo.

To put it in terms of pseudo code:

- read repository
- load site
- print layout
- perform tasks
  -- and repeat.

Another option to consider is using a database that tracks the layout of the repository independently. This way, you're sure users won't bump into eachothers updates and it keeps the repository database safe from corruption.

Answer (score 0):

1. you should use direct repository access via file:// this comparable to a slow hd (if you have fast CPU and HD)
2. use the svn bindings for your respective scripting language, do **not** rely on xml parsing, as they are much slower
3. do not read the **whole** tree out, but maintain a navigational hierarchy and read directories on demand, usually if you read the whole hierarchy, you end up with hundreds/thousands directories in the deeper levels which are usually not interesting for your application, so you can omit them and display them on demand(if user browse this deep)
4. if you are doing svn access modifications use the entries in your access file to get to know your important directories beforehand